# How to change the max value of a progressbar in pythonsimplegui?

Tags: python

I want to create a progressbar which has the length of the list as its max value.
I initialize it with max value 1000, but I want to change it after reading a csv file and getting the length of it. But it doesn't work as I expect.
How can I achieve it?
Below is my current code.

````
from read_csv import get_csv_list
file_input_col = [sg.Text('CSV file'),
                  sg.InputText(key='INPUT_FILE', enable_events=True, size=(45,1)),
                  sg.FileBrowse('browse', file_types=((('CSV file', '*.csv'),)))]

ok_button = [sg.OK()]
cancel_button = [sg.Cancel()]
progress_bar = [sg.ProgressBar(1000, orientation='h', size=(20, 20), key='progressbar')]

# window layout
layout = [  file_input_col,
            ok_button,
            cancel_button,
            progress_bar]

# Create window object
window = sg.Window('test', layout)
progress_bar = window['progressbar']


# loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event =='OK':
        keyword_list = get_csv_list(values['INPUT_FILE'])
        progress_bar.update(max=len(keyword_list))
        for i in range(1000): # I will change this for loop later
            progress_bar.UpdateBar(i+1)
            event, values = window.read(timeout=10)
            if event == 'Cancel'  or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                progress_bar.UpdateBar(0)
                break
window.close()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pythonsimplegui ProgressBar Class uses a TKinter ProgressBar object called TKProgressBar to display the GUI. If the `update` method for the pythonsimplegui ProgressBar is not working as expected, you can try updating their TKinter ProgressBar directly instead:

```py
progress_bar.TKProgressBar.TKProgressBarForReal.config(maximum=1000, length=len(keyword_list))
progress_bar.max_value = len(keyword_list)
```